# DAX PowerPivot Function ignoring specific dates in week

Tags: dax, powerpivot, measure

I am trying to build a function in DAX that sums up the total hours, where we have OCM for that specific day (orange highlighted):

[image]

It means that on the 9th and 10th, we do not have OCM, but on all other days. Hence, summing all OCM days should provide me 4,365.5 hours.

Any idea what formula could solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work, assuming you want to consider the same week and station_code. Otherwise remove them from the ALLEXCEPT or change the ALLEXCEPT to ALL(T)

```
Hours Non OCM :=
VAR filteredDates =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( T[date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT (
            T,
            T[week],
            T[station_code]
        ),
        T[OCM_flag] = "OCM"
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( T[hours] ),
        filteredDates
    )
```